# What is difference between * and ** in springFrameWorkMvc.webMVCConfig?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have studied about spring, especially spring-boot.

So I made a project, set config into this project. But I didn't know spring well.

So I searched these things, just copied the codes.

And now I find a strange thing that I mentioned in title. Please see below codes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMVCAutoConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

      registry.addResourceHandler("/*")
              .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");


      //I used this for get some images out of the project.
      registry.addResourceHandler("/external/**")
              .addResourceLocations("file:D:///resource/");
   }

}
```

As you can see, both 'addResourceHandler' have * in argument.

But I can not understand why I have to use two * in bottom-code.

From I write this codes, When I access by http://localhost:port/pre-setting-url, It works.

But If I use only one * in bottom-code, pre-setting-url are not work. I can not get images.

I know the meaning of * as 'all', But it is not?

What is the meaning of * and **

Help me!

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/*` means any resource **directly** under */* like */foo* or */bar*, but not */foo/something*.

`**` also includes subresources, so `/external/**` matches */external/foo/something*  or */external/foo/somethingelse*.

Comment: It is cool and simple. thank you so much. be happy!